# How to center three div on all browsers?

Tags: html, css

```
<div style="width: 400px; height: 150px; background-color: red">LOGO</div>
<div style="width: 200px; height: 1000px; float: left">sfsdf </div>
<div>sdad</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AuT7n/

How can i center these three div on all browsers?

Comment: Center them one below the other, or three in one row?

Comment: all page, with this three div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an extra div to hold the bottom two.

```
<div class="centre" style="width: 400px; height: 150px; background-color: red">LOGO</div>
<div class="centre" style="width: 400px; height: 1000px; ">
   <div style="width: 200px; height: 1000px; float: left; background-color: green">sfsdf </div>
   <div style="width: 200px; height: 1000px; float: right; background-color: purple">sdad</div>
</div>
```

with the style:

```
div.centre {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
display:block;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
div {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
display:block;    
}
```

If you want text only div to center as well you will need to add

```
text-align:center;
```

Also this won't work properly while you have float:left; on. Since your telling it to float to the left and be centered at the same time.

http://jsfiddle.net/AuT7n/7/

Comment: "float: left" makes the 2nd div float left

Comment: See the one I posted. You need text-align:center; for text only divs and remove float:left;